# Custom unit test folder/path doesn't see custom src folder/path in Maven project when using terminal

Tags: eclipse, maven, terminal, java-7

I have a custom structure in my project of

```
Development -
            -  src
            -  test
```

and running tests works fine through eclipse but when I use the terminal on my mac to run the test (mvn test), the src classes are not found (fails during maven compile plugin). I figure it has to be an issue with my pom not guiding the plugins to the right folders. If I comment out this line,

```
 <outputDirectory>Development/build</outputDirectory>
```

it works fine because the .class files r now being placed in the target folder. Instead of looking at the target folder for the.class files, I need maven to look at the

```
Development/build
```

directory if I'm not mistaken. Right?

I would like to continue to use my custom file structure and correct my pom so that it compiles and runs unit test through my mac's terminals.

```
<build>
   <sourceDirectory>Development/src/main</sourceDirectory>
   <testSourceDirectory>Development/src/test</testSourceDirectory>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.5.1</version>
         <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
            <outputDirectory>Development/build</outputDirectory>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.3.1</version>
         <configuration>
            <classesDirectory>Development/build</classesDirectory>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.0</version>
         <executions>
            <execution>
               <id>auto-clean</id>
               <phase>clean</phase>
               <goals>
                  <goal>clean</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                  <filesets>
                     <fileset>
                        <directory>Development/build</directory>
                     </fileset>
                  </filesets>
               </configuration>
            </execution>
         </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
         <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.1.0</version>
         <configuration>
            <descriptors>
               <descriptor>Development/src/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
            </descriptors>
            <tarLongFileMode>posix</tarLongFileMode>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>single</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

This is the console output

```
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean) @ weatherdetails ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/username/git/weatherdetails/target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (auto-clean) @ weatherdetails ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ weatherdetails ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/username/git/weatherdetails/src/main/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ weatherdetails ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2503 source files to /Users/username/git/weatherdetails/Development/build
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ weatherdetails ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/username/git/weatherdetails/src/test/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ weatherdetails ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to /Users/username/git/weatherdetails/Development/build
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/username/git/weatherdetails/Development/src/test/com/wfc/schedulers/WeeklySchedulerTest.java:[12,26] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class WeeklyScheduler
  location: package com.wfc.schedulers
```

Any suggestions on what's not configured correctly?

Comment: Follow the conventions over configuration paradigm and do not change things like `sourceDirectory>Development/src/main</sourceDirectory>` cause there is no advantage in it....

Comment: I actually had a talk with my lead about that today. I said the point of using maven is that its folder structure is a standard. We're going to have to tell every technology we use to look in the Development/builder folder for everything and that somewhat defeats the purpose if you ask me.

Comment: This thing is called convention over configuration paradigm. The consequence of your setup is simply that you need many configuration changes which are not needed if you follow the defaults (in particular the folder structure)...this makes it easier to use it and also for others to use it. This save time and money...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this work shortly after making this post but wanted to see if someone had a different answer. While formatting this post to meet the stackoverflow standards, I noticed the compiler plugin was writing the classes to /Users/username/git/weatherdetails/Development/build. i said wait thats wrong. it should write them to /Users/username/git/weatherdetails/Development/build/classes and /Users/username/git/weatherdetails/Development/build/test-classes. i googled how to change the target directory in the pom and ran into this tag

```
<directory>Development/build</directory>
```

I added it to the build and removed the

```
<outputDirectory>Development/build</outputDirectory>
```

tag from the compiler plugin because i added it there thinking that it was creating the custom target folder in the path. Ran it and it worked. So now my build looks like this

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>Development/src/main</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>Development/src/test</testSourceDirectory>
        <!-- if you put just Development, it will erase everything in the development folder -->
        <directory>Development/build</directory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
        <classesDirectory>Development/build</classesDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>auto-clean</id>
                        <phase>clean</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clean</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filesets>
                                <fileset>
                    <directory>Development/build</directory>
                                </fileset>
                            </filesets>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>       <descriptor>Development/src/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                    <tarLongFileMode>posix</tarLongFileMode>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Hope this helps someone!